# Get-WMIObject powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, bluetooth, com, wmi

i have my code in powershell to print the COM port

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
try {
Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object DeviceID, PNPDeviceID | Where-Object{$_.PNPDeviceID -like "*$env:asset*"} 
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "Nessuna porta COM trovata, assicurarsi che il dispositivo sia correttamente collegato"
    $LASTEXITCODE = 1
    exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

this is the results:

```
DeviceID PNPDeviceID                                                                                             
-------- -----------                                                                                             
COM4     BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_LOCALMFG&0000\7&2A34F9CE&0&000000000000_00000006         
COM3     BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}_VID&000101E6_PID&1128\7&2A34F9CE&0&000780F5F461_C00000000
```

I just want it to show this:

```
DeviceID                                                                                             
--------                                                                                              
COM4              
COM3
```

How can i obtain this result?
Thanks in advice!

Comment: you SPECIFICALLY told it to put those two properties into your new object >>> `Select-Object DeviceID, PNPDeviceID` <<< if you do not want the 2nd property ... don't include it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by Changing the third Line by below code.

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort |
    Select-Object DeviceID, PNPDeviceID |
    Where-Object{$_.PNPDeviceID -like "*$env:asset*"}).DeviceID
```